# Create a type from a const object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a Field type:

```
type Field = { name: string; type: 'string' | 'number' };
```

And a list of Fields.

```
const fields = [
    { name: 'field1', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'field2', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'field3', type: 'number' }
] as const satisfies readonly Field[];
```

Is it possible to infer `fields` into a type that looks like the below type?

```
type MyObject = {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
    field3: number;
}
```

The closest I could get to is:

```
type MyObject = Record<typeof fields[number]["name"], typeof fields[number]["type"]>;
```

which yields:

```
{field1: "string" | "number", field2: "string" | "number", field3: "string" | "number"}
```

Close, but not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Field = { name: string; type: 'string' | 'number' };
const fields = [
    { name: 'field1', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'field2', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'field3', type: 'number' }
] as const satisfies readonly Field[];

type NameMap = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
}
type X<T extends readonly Field[]> = { [K in T[number]['name']]: NameMap[Extract<T[number], { name: K }>['type']] }
type MyObject = X<typeof fields>
//   ^?
// type MyObject = {
//     field1: string;
//     field2: string;
//     field3: number;
// }
```